# Why won't the program recognize the second button click?

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason the program is not recognizing the second button click, it recognizes the first one it performs the action, but when I click another button in another cell, it does not recognize the action. Below is the code for the button added to each cell as well as the button function. When the button is clicked for x cell, it will take that title and run it through the itunes search api and play the preview link. It works when I click the button for x cell, but when I click another button in another cell nothing happens. Why? How do I fix this?

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")




    cell.textLabel?.text = ret[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ter[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lombok", size: 22)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor =  UIColorFromRGB("4A90E2")
    cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lombok", size: 16)
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor =  UIColor.blackColor()

    let playButton : UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    playButton.tag = indexPath.row
    let imageret = "playbutton"
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: imageret), forState: .Normal)
    playButton.frame = CGRectMake(230, 20, 100, 100)
    playButton.addTarget(self,action: "playit:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    for view: UIView in cell.contentView.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }


    cell.contentView.addSubview(playButton)


    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()






    return cell
}





func playit(sender: UIButton!) {

    let playButtonrow = sender.tag

    print(ret[playButtonrow])

    let searchTerm: String = ret[playButtonrow]

    let itunesSearchTerm = searchTerm.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)

   if let escapedSearchTerm = itunesSearchTerm.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    let urlPath = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(escapedSearchTerm)&media=music"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let ctn: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!


    print("Search iTunes API at URL \(url)")

    ctn.start()

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            if let dict: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            {


                let previewUrl = NSURL(string: (dict["results"]![0]["previewUrl"] as? String)!)!
                        print(previewUrl)
                player = AVPlayer(URL: previewUrl)
                player.rate = 1.0
                player.play()



            }
        } catch let jsonError as NSError {

        }
    }
    task.resume()



    }

}
```

Comment: to be honest, there are so many things which are incorrect with your code that you should fix those first. 1) Don't create cells in your cellForRow method. Instead deque them. 2) View setup should not be done each time. Do it only once. Also, you need to clarify what you mean by "it's not working". Have you added print() to your playIt method and verified that it is not called? Or is it called, but does nothing?

Comment: I will get 1. and 2. fixed, but yes I have a print() in my playit method. It prints everything when it is clicked the first time, but when it is clicked a second time, nothing prints

Comment: can you remove the first line in your function? The one where you dequeue the cell? Firstly, you do not reference that cell anywhere. Secondly, I feel that it might be doing something weird as you did not set any reuse identifiers for your cells

Comment: My cells have a identifier "cell", and I will update the code, but it is stil not working.

Comment: Make the background color of your button red and check that nothing obscures it. Maybe the text is longer on the cell on which the function is not called

Comment: http://puu.sh/leDzP/9ea41112d3.png

Comment: can you upload your code to GitHub? I can't really come up with any other ideas without playing with the app :(

Answer (score 0):

`playit:` not called at all?

Try to use proper `table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, not `playit`

Try remove `let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")`

Better not to remove the subviews and add again, reset the target methods.

Comment: the removeFromSuperview will make sure there is only one button, no overlaps. My playit method is in the code above.

Comment: I tried removing `let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")`, but nothing happens when I click the button. Originally, it worked the first time.

Comment: replace the first line of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell`

Comment: I did that, but I'm getting the same results

Comment: Did `playit` ever been called for the second button? Have you tried by putting a break point in the first line of this function?

Answer (score 0):

Bad options:
1)Try Debug - View Debugging - Capture View Hierarchy to see if there is nothing else higher than you button in your hierarchy.

2) add you button code on -willDisplayCell

Better option:
Subclass UItableViewCell and add your button in subclass.

(and for god sake! Use
 var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell)